# Jackson to not to include default values in serialization not set by user

Tags: java, jackson

I have one integer field and couple of string fields defined in pojo and class has @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT) annotation defined.
Serialization is excluding the integer field though it set by using setter method.

Is there any way to include a filed in serialization with it's default value if it is set explicitly?

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Recommendation {
      private int index;
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;

      // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Jackson has no idea if a setter has been called or not on an object it serializes. The field has the default value, you've told Jackson that default values should not be serialized, so it doesn't serializes them. Just remove that annotation, and it will serialize them. Why does it matter anyway? The receiver should assume the value is the default value when it's absent, since that's how you chose to design it.

Comment: If 0 has a different meaning than absent, then you should have two separate values for absent and 0: make it an Integer, null means absent, and 0 means 0.